# Vanishing of Zariski motivic sheaf

Tags: motivic-cohomology

Let X be a smooth variety over a field. Is it true in general that the sheaf $\mathcal{H}^{r}(\mathbb{Z}(s))=0$ if $r>s \geq 0$? Here $\mathcal{H}^{r}(\mathbb{Z}(s))=0$ is the sheaf associated to the presheaf on the Zariski site $U \mapsto H_{\mathcal{M}}^{r}(U, \mathbb{Z}(s))$.

Comment: My question is related to another one posted here. If the above statement is true, we can show that there is an isomorphism $H^{s}(X, K_{r}^{M}) \cong H_{\mathcal{M}}^{r+s}(X, \mathbb{Z}(r))$ when $r=s+2$ and $dim(X)=s+1$. This is the case I care about.                                                                              http://mathoverflow.net/questions/122072/motivic-cohomology-and-cohomology-of-milnor-k-theory-sheaf?rq=1

Comment: This is true. It suffices to check at stalks, where the question is local. This paper of Kerz ([The Gersten conjecture for Milnor K-theory](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-008-0144-8)) proves this on the top of page 6.